# Specify custom guard property for Caliburn.Micro Action Message

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Using Caliburn.Micro, I can have a guard property that defines the IsEnabled state of e.g. a button:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="DoSomething" Content="Do it"/>
```

And in the ViewModel

```
public bool CanDoSomething { get {...} }

public void DoSomething() {... }
```

My problem is that I have a lot of buttons and corresponding actions in a ribbon menu. Almost all buttons have the same guard logic, something like "enabled if the application is not busy with some long running operation". My VM tends to get cluttered with many "CanXYZ" properties that all have the same content. Of course all guard properties can delegate to one single property containing the actual logic, but is there a way to avoid all those single guard properties? Something like

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="DoSomething" cal:Message.Attach.Guard="IsAppIdle" Content="Do it"/>
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Not impossible to do it but then `DoSomething` is hooked up in the `ViewModel` and the way Caliburn Micro works is that it looks for the properties in the datacontext. I can see this ending up with a static class that it can invoke when `RaiseCanExecute` is called.

`Attach` is also an attached property. You'll have to change the property to a class that contains `Guard` so you'll have to end up writing what I suggested or extending caliburn micro's `Message` class.